# Heroku PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg

I'm new to Heroku and just tried to deploy a python music discord bot (deploying from GitHub branch).

The deployment is successful the bot is working.
However, when I tried to play a music, it gives me an error:

```
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596654+00:00 app[worker.1]: voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596654+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 225, in __init__
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596656+00:00 app[worker.1]: super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596666+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 138, in __init__
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596668+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596689+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 144, in _spawn_process
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596689+00:00 app[worker.1]: process = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW, **subprocess_kwargs)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596699+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596700+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596708+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596709+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596743+00:00 app[worker.1]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596743+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596744+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596744+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596746+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596778+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596780+00:00 app[worker.1]: await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596788+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/bot.py", line 665, in on_command_error
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596789+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise error
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596798+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596799+00:00 app[worker.1]: await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596808+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596808+00:00 app[worker.1]: await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596817+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596817+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2021-09-17T01:24:43.596833+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
```

Problem in `bot.py`:

```
voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
```

The path to `ffmpeg.exe` is already correct in GitHub respository; but it doesn't work and gives this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Notes:

- I don't know how to add FFmpeg in Heroku, so I manually add it into the GitHub repository (the last time I tried without FFmpeg in GitHub and use [this](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest) build pack for Heroku, it throws an error `ClientException: ffmpeg.exe was not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Heroku gives you access to a virtual shell that uses a linux distribution under the hood. Given that `*.exe` files don't run in linux (at least not directly), you will not be able to make it run. Besides, for security reasons (among others) they shouldn't let people write on certain directories or execute arbitrary binaries like your `ffmpeg.exe`.

First make sure you are able to connect to said shell and try to run `ffmpeg`. If you are not able to run it, you should create an issue in the GitHub [repo](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest) that provides the buildpack you mentioned, explaining the problem you are having.